# Using WHERE Clause based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two existing tables.

Table_A:

```
Sector, Account_ID
```

Table_B:

```
Customer_ID, Seller_ID, Amount
```

In the following statement:

```
SELECT
    AC.Sector Customer_Sector,
    AS.Sector Seller_Sector,
    B.*
FROM
    Table_A AC,
    Table_A AS,
    Table_B B
WHERE
    AC.Account_ID = B.Customer_ID AND 
    AS.Account_ID = B.Seller_ID
```

Not all rows in `Table_B` have both `Customer_ID` and `Seller_ID`.

How to write the `WHERE` clause with conditions to achieve this logic:

```
IF B.Customer ID IS NULL
   THEN omit the clause of 'AC.Account_ID = B.Customer_ID'
END IF

IF B.Seller_ID IS NULL
   THEN omit the clause of 'AS.Account_ID = B.Seller_ID'
END IF
```

Comment: First, use proper JOIN syntax.   The ON clause can be your friend here.  Update your query using JOIN syntax, and you might get the answer...

Comment: 2 characters aliases are only slightly better than 1 character ones. Stop being so cryptic. And use aliases that are easily read as distinct values.

Comment: @SMor most of the recommendations I've seen for table aliases has been to use 1 or 2 character aliases, just ensuring that they relate to the table e.g. P for Person etc.